# Are Domain Models needed in simple REST API webservice?

Tags: design-patterns

The usual pattern I see is three layers for the Model: Service layer, Domain layer, and Data Layer. In this pattern, the Domain Layer handles most of the business logic.

For REST services which does mostly just CRUD with minimal business logic, could the Domain Layer be excluded? Can the business logic be pushed to the Service layer instead?

Comment: what's the business logic of a CRUD app ?

Answer (score 0):

For *REST* services mostly *MVC* design pattern is followed.

The client is usually the view. The controller controls the services and model is responsible for the database interactions.

In your case the Service Layer can be broken into *Controller* and *Model*.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to leak the complexity of the domain model through the API to the clients, you can use it.

However, I think in case of small projects the benefits of having separate models does not justify the cost of separating the models.